# My gradients don't show up in my Android project

Tags: android, dialog, gradient

I'm new to the Android platform and I'm developing an app that where the main activity
is using the dialog theme.

I have the ui setup pretty much the way I want but gradients don't seem to be working for me.
I've tried a gradient title bar, view, layout, textView etc and in every case the gradient does not display. (I've only tested it on the simulator so far).

My drawable xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#00000000"
      android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF"
      android:endColor="#00000000"
      android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

and I use the following to set the background to several elements but it never shows up:

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
```

I've tried different colors and angles etc etc but to no avail.

If I do the following it works however I prefer to do this in xml.

```
GradientDrawable grad = new GradientDrawable(
      Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
      new int[] {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW}
    );
    this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(grad);
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting opaque colors on the whole gradient.

For example, use `#FF000000` for black. The two first hex numbers are the alpha value.

Answer (score 0):

your code is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#00000000"
      android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF"
      android:endColor="#00000000"
      android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

that is working fine and dispaying gredient correctly on Android HTC Hero phone !! It may be a case that gredient effect may not be showing up on Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I've determined that it works on an actual device so it must be an emulator issue.